# Scalatest Double equivalency in list of case classes

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have `Double` values that are going to be similar in value, but not exact.  Normally I would do:

```
val a: Double = ???
val b: Double = ???

a shouldEqual b +- 0.25
```

And if I was just comparing a single case class I would do:

```
case class Data(label: String, value: Double)
val a: Data = ???
val b: Data = ???
a.value shouldEqual b.value +- 0.25
```

In my case, I have a list of case class instances, and would like to compare them with a tolerance for their `value` attributes:

```
val output = Seq(Data("a", 1.1), Data("b", 1.2))
val expected = Seq(Data("a", 0.9), Data("b", 1.1))
output should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs expected
```

Of course, that would file because the `value` attributes do not match exactly.  What I need is something like this:

```
output should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs expected +- 0.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up defining a custom `Matcher` for my `Seq[Data]` type:

```
trait CustomMatcher {

  class SeqDataContainsTheSameElementsInOrderAs(expected: Seq[Data]) {

    override def apply(left: Seq[Data]): MatchResult = {

      // ... do other checks like comparing the length and such

      val bad = left.zip(expected).filter(t => {
        val difference = Math.abs(t._1.value - t._2.value)
        difference > TOLERANCE // Declare this somewhere
      })

      // Return the MatchResult, you will probably want to give better error messages than this
      MatchResult(
        bad.isEmpty,
        s"""Some of the values were not equal""",
        s"""Everything was equal"""
      )
    }

    def customContainTheSameElementsInOrderAs(expected: Seq[Data]) = new SeqDataContainsTheSameElementsInOrderAs(expected)
  }
}
```

Then I use it like:

```
output should customContainTheSameElementsInOrderAs(expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just go with

```
forAll(output.zipAll(expected, null, null)) {
  case (a, b) => a.value shouldEqual b.value +- 0.25
}
```

Using `zipAll` because `zip` would incorrectly succeed when lengths don't match, but the error message you get this way isn't too good.