# How to compare case classes with floating numbers in Scalatest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Can you compare two objects that have floating numbers in field or values of maps, without manually comparing each field; i.e., enforce tolerance whenever floats or doubles are encountered using [custom matchers](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#usingCustomMatchers) and Scala generics?

Comment: It looks like you know what to do but you don't want to write the code. It sounds like some sort of homework/assignment problem or interview question. What is the difficulty with custom matchers or floating points that you are facing? What have you tried?

Comment: you can convert them to string and then compare

Comment: The same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236592/scalatest-double-equivalency-in-list-of-case-classes